parallel=false available at feature level in addition to scenario?
We have multiple teams that create test within their respective services, but lately, we have been running into issues when we do a full environment regression in which features from different teams update or read the same data (customer payment updates versus agent payment updates).  While in the process of the tests, there are assertions made that the data was updated correctly, but for feature 1-test A, it was seeing data that was updated in feature 2-test B or viceversa.  Both feature files have @parallel=false above the Feature: hoever, this does not appear to work across features.
Is there any way to prevent clashes across multiple feature files that may touch the similar resources (ideally all update/change and then verify data tests)?
Update with sample code using website in previous example 'https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com'
auth and booking setup (simulating our login to a shared account)
@karateTest
Feature: API test using RESTfulBooker application
Background:
    * def testUrl = 'https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com'

    * def booking =
    """
    {
      firstname: 'Mikes', lastname: 'Test',
      totalprice: 500, depositpaid: true,
      additionalneeds: 'SampleData',
      bookingdates: { checkin: '2024-07-18', checkout: '2024-07-18' }
    }
    """

    * url testUrl

  Scenario: Auth and booking creation
  # obtain token
    * path 'auth'
    * request { username: 'admin', password: 'password123' }
    * method post
    * status 200
    * def authCookie = 'token=' + response.token

  # configure common headers for all calls
    * def testHeaders = { Accept : 'application/json', Cookie: '#(authCookie)' }
    * configure headers = testHeaders

  # create booking - Done initially to setup data and then commented out
    * path 'booking'
    * request booking
    * method post
    * status 200
    * match response contains { bookingid: '#number', booking: '#(booking)' }
    * def bookingid = response.bookingid

Created 10 copies of this to show the issue (since this is a simple test with a single function and execution is very quick
@karateTestUpdate
Feature: API test using RESTfulBooker application
Background:
    * karate.set( karate.callSingle('karateSampleRestfulBookerUpdatesOnlyAuth.feature') )
    * url testUrl
    * configure headers = testHeaders

  Scenario: update and verify price
    # find booking by bookingid
    * path 'booking',bookingid
    * method get
    * status 200
    * match $.firstname == "Mikes"
    * match $.lastname == "Test"

    # update booking
    * def newPrice = function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) }
    * booking.totalprice = newPrice(1000)

    * path 'booking', bookingid
    * request booking
    * method put
    * status 200

    # find booking by bookingid to verify price update for booking
    * path 'booking',bookingid
    * method get
    * status 200
    * match $.totalprice == booking.totalprice

Running this in the 10 separate files, in parallel, here is the result

You can see that only one passed.  Here is the results of the first run showing that the updates was for 497, but the result was 219


We invite contributions to improve the existing @parallel=false implementation, but yes, it leans towards parallelism where possible, which is what most teams want. It is a good practice to ensure all your tests are independent, else you will always struggle and never have confidence in your tests. Worse, you will never get the speed benefit of running tests in parallel.
Anyway, the only suggestion I can think of is that you should write a small singleton Java class that can execute a global lock and now you can call this piece of code from anywhere where you want to guarantee that only one thread is running. For example:
* def Lock = Java.type('my.co.LockUtils')
* Lock.acquire()
# do stuff
* Lock.release()

This may open you up to all kinds of other Java threading issues and also slow down your tests significantly or even hang them, so you have to figure this out on your own.

With different teams working on tests independantly, I am unsure that it is possible to ensure the work from one does not overlap another teams.  When running independantly, everything is fine, but when bringing the organization together for a release validation in an environment, that is where we see the issues.  I wonder how others handle this as I can't see this not being an issue in bigger companies, that have multiple teams developing tests.

@mike for what it's worth, most enterprise teams seem to be doing fine. If everyone tries to use the same database records, of course you will see issues, and teams typically have some rules - for example that a) each Scenario is responsible for creating the data that is used for that test and b) any "wildcard" query result assertions are "lenient" enough to ignore data that has been inserted by other tests.

yes, we have separate scenarios that create the data, but teams may update data differently depending on their scenario, so when validating information to ensure the update was a success, we see the conflict.  Maybe we jsut have to put ALL updates in a single shared feature, and test from there, but that brings in its own problems.

@mike no I did not say separate scenarios to create the data, quite the opposite. for the benefit of others who may come across this thread, take a look at this example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/blob/main/src/test/java/app/api/simple/restful-booker.feature - no matter how many people run it at the same time, it will pass for everyone - it is worth studying

Added sample test that is more in line with our tests as we apply updates to accounts from different services, the update itself or the validation fails due to the data being related to a different call

Has the sample code been attempted as it does not work as you state and I have shown
